# what is the transaction per second of hyperledger fabric with Kafka

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to know that how much transactions can be take place in one second over hyperledger fabric with Kafka protocol.

I'm creating a network, as such project size is not as much big but if my product will do millions of transactions per second around the globe and want to log those transactions over hyperledger fabric so could it be possible that fabric can manage them all?

If yes than how many nodes should i need to setup first and what should be the server specs to deploy the network.
And if this is not the good idea of using fabric than kindly let me know which blockchain should i use to log the immutable and consortium ledger.

Answer (score 0):

As Hyperledger Fabric is a scalable platform, you may scale it to fit your needs. But as your project will do millions of transactions per second, you can apply more than just adding new nodes to increase TPS(Transactions Per Second). Like,

- Using IPFS based chain storage to store bulky data off the chain and have the proof hash on the hyperledger fabric.
- Indexing the CouchDB underneath for speed and scalability that suits your need.
- Using **high throughput network** provided by Hyperledger Fabric itself
- Increasing the number of endorser channels

Now, for the hardware requirements, there has been an experiment done at IBM with a single node of 4vCPU and 16GB memory with SSDs, the following data has been found-

1. Using 2 endorsers -> 785 TPS
2. Using 4 endorsers -> 948 TPS
3. Using 8 endorsers -> 1265 TPS